# How to Check the parent enviroment (eg multicols) in which a custom environment is embedded

Tags: environments, multicol

Is there anyway to check if a custom environment is embedded in another parent environment.

In the following example. a custom environment myenv is both inside a multicol and outside multicol.  I know the @currenvit contains the current environment.  I need to check at the start of my custom environment myenv, in red text, if the custom myenv is inside the multicols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\whereamI}{%
    \par\@currenvir\par
    \ifx\@currenvir\@myenvname
    (\@currenvir~true)
    \else
    {\color{brown}(false myenv, it is in ~\@currenvir)}
    \fi}
\newcommand*\@myenvname{myenv}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{myenv}[0]{%
    {(\color{red}at start of~\whereamI I would like to test if parent environment is multicols) }
}{}


\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{myenv}
        Want to test if parent is multicols
    \end{myenv}
    {\color{blue} Inside multicols and outside myenv\whereamI}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `before` environment hook. Seems to work. (documentation in lthooks.pdf)

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\whereamI}{%
    \par\@currenvir\par
    \ifx\@currenvir\@myenvname
    (\@currenvir~true)
    \else
    {\color{brown}(false myenv, it is in ~\@currenvir)}
    \fi}
\newcommand*\@myenvname{myenv}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{myenv}[0]{%
    {(\color{red}at start of~\whereamI parent environment is \parentenvir) }
    %                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    %                      it can be used like this, how to check if it's equal to multicols is left as an exercise to the reader
}{}

% ======== start of important code ========
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/myenv/before}{\let\parentenvir\@currenvir}
\makeatother
% ======== end of important code ========

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{myenv}
        Want to test if parent is multicols
    \end{myenv}
    {\color{blue} Inside multicols and outside myenv\whereamI}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Rename `\parentenvir` to something else if you prefer.

Comment: (there's no guarantee what the value of the macro might be if it's not used inside the start block of `myenv`.)